# why I cannot save the data obtained from the firebase service

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {        
      this.profileService.getBasicProfile(this.uid).subscribe(
        basic => {
          console.log(basic);   //line 1
          this.usedBasicProfile = basic;
          console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);   //line 2
        }  
      )
      console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);  //line 3
}
```

Service.ts

```
    savedBasicProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserBasic>;

getBasicProfile(uid: string) {
    this.savedBasicProfile = this.af.database.object('/users/user'+uid);
    console.log(this.savedBasicProfile);
    return this.savedBasicProfile;
}
```

the console.log of line 1 and line 2 work correctly, but the line 3 output is undefined.
Any help would be appreciated.

///////////////////////////edit

```
  constructor(
  private authService: AuthGuard,
  private profileService: ProfileService
) 
{
  this.uid = this.authService.getUid();      
  console.log(this.uid);

  this.profileService.getBasicProfile(this.uid).subscribe(
    basic => {
      this.usedBasicProfile = basic;  //how to make this line work?
    }  
  );
  console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand the async process involved in Observables.

```
ngOnInit() {        
      this.profileService.getBasicProfile(this.uid) executed
      console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);  //line 3  executed
}
```

First the service call is made and line 3 is executed. 
When the data is returned then only the subscribe will be triggered at that time you will get the values

```
.subscribe( ///called  only when the data is returned
            basic => {
              console.log(basic);   //line 1 executed
              this.usedBasicProfile = basic;
              console.log(this.usedBasicProfile);   //line 2
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what the problem is, but after I try something, I still have no idea how to make the code in the .subsribe() executed. Could you please give me a example? Thanks a lot

Comment: it cannot be done. Observables are designed like that

Comment: eh...or anyway could make  this.usedBasicProfile = basic;  this line of code work?

Comment: put inside constructor instead of ngOnInit

Comment: I am sorry, but I have try before.... still not work, could you please explain it in deep detail?......I am very grateful to your patience

Comment: Not solved yet, I just do not know how to fix it. How to make the code in the                                this.usedBasicProfile = basic ....work

Comment: I have follow what you say to put the code into the constructor() , and I edit my code above, could you please help me to solve it......I am going to crazy

Comment: I cannot make the    this.usedBasicProfile    get the value from the service